Polars: What are the downsides of joining on null?
join_nulls is False by default in polars.
Suppose I were to always call join with join_nulls set to True. What problems would I run into?
Put differently: why would I not want to join on null? If it is because I want to filter out null values, then wouldn't I call drop_null explicitly on the relevant dataframe(s) before joining, rather than relying on join to implicitly do this for me?

Not sure if it's done on purpose in Polars, but this is ANSI behavior in SQL. You can't compare null with another value (including null) directly. See, for example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

There is some discussion in the bug report: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9738 and the PR that introduced the parameter: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/12840 - what stands out to me is: "missing data matching has quadratic behavior"

@jqurious thanks, that's helpful. The comment which stands out feels like it should've been "potentially has quadratic behavior". I'd not expect actual implementation to be much different, it's just if one doesn't expect nulls to match and has a lot of missing data, then it might explode.


Every null matches every other null. This means that if you have n nulls, you will get n^2 matches. This is often surprising for people, and can cause massive blow-ups in time.

It's the default in SQL to not match nulls in joins, so this is consistent with that as well.


